# How warm is the sea in Lanzarote in the Canaries in February?

Tags: weather-and-climate, canary-islands, swimming

I'll be in Lanzarote in February. I've been there in high summer when of course it was very hot but what's the sea temperature like in February?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About 18 degrees Celsius, give or take:

http://www.bigblueplanet.com/watersearch.jsp?Longitude=0&Latitude=0&Month=2&WaterDepth=Surface&Zoom=2

And that website seriously hurts my eyes.

Somewhat more readable, but not giving historical details:

http://www.sea-temperature.com/water/lanzarote/165

Comment: The first link actually says 18 degrees if you scroll down, not 20, and the second page is for Tenerife, NOT Lanzarote.  They do differ.

Comment: Indeed it does. My eyes were hurting so much that the map was good enough for me. I minimized brightness on my screen to check.

Comment: I see you fixed the temp now, but second link still points to Tenerife ;)  It also doesn't give Feb data - just annual averages :/  I'll update the link to their Lanzarote page, but yeah, it doesn't really answer the Feb question...

Comment: omg... over two years later.. and that website STILL HURTS MY EYES!

Answer (score 8):

**Air temperature**

Most of the islands are pretty similar in climate, but [Wikipedia has a great chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canary_Islands#Climate) for temperatures of Gran Canaria and Tenerife, indicating that the average high in February is around 21 degrees Celsius, the mean temperature for the day is 18 deg, and the average low is 15 deg.  You can also expect 1 in 8-10 days to have rain, on average.

For more specifically Lanzarote details, we had to hunt through the [Agencia Estatal de Meteorología](http://www.aemet.es/en/portada) - the metereological agency used as a source for the above Wikipedia data.  And yes, they have a [climate page on Lanzarote](http://www.aemet.es/en/serviciosclimaticos/datosclimatologicos/valoresclimatologicos?l=C029O&k=coo).

This indicates that 17.5 is the daily average, the average high is 21.2, the average low is 13.9 and in terms of rainfall, you can expect 14mm over 3 days of the month, on average.

**Sea temperature**

For the ocean, we have to go to different websites. I'll provide three:

- [Holiday Weather](http://www.holiday-weather.com/lanzarote/averages/#sea_temperature) - indicating that in February the average sea temperature is 18 degrees.
- [IberVillas](http://www.ibervillas.com/Lanzarote%20Weather.htm) agrees with this - indicating 18 degrees as well.
- [Big Blue Planet](http://www.bigblueplanet.com/watersearch.jsp?Longitude=0&Latitude=0&Month=2&WaterDepth=Surface&Zoom=2) - scroll down to the list of places, or search for Lanzarote on the page, and it also says 18, so we're looking pretty confident in this regard.